# Any way to transform nested list to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have sparsed dataframe that I needed to convert it to list which I already did it. Now I want to transform this list to dictionary, so I can do key-value comparison in my actual use case. To do so, I attempted to convert list to dictionary but I have value error instead. How can I do this correctly in python? Does anyone knows what is correct way to do this in python?

**reproducible data and my attempt**

```
mydict={'code0': {0: 'nan', 1: " '40'", 2: " '98'", 3: " '98'", 4: " '52'", 5: " '52'", 6: " '52'", 7: " '52'", 8: " '40'", 9: " '58'"}, 'code1': {0: "  ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL')", 1: 'nan', 2: " ('ATT','NC')", 3: " ('ATT','VA','NC')", 4: " 'NC'", 5: " 'NC'", 6: " 'NC'", 7: " 'NC'", 8: " 'VA'", 9: " 'CE'"}, 'code2': {0: 'nan', 1: 'nan', 2: " ('103','104','105','106','31')", 3: " ('104','105','106','31')", 4: " '109'", 5: " '109'", 6: " '109'", 7: " '109'", 8: " '11'", 9: " ('109')"}, 'code3': {0: 'nan', 1: " '518'", 2: " '810'", 3: 'nan', 4: " ('610','620','682','642','621','611')", 5: " ('396','340','394','393','240')", 6: " ('612','790','110')", 7: " ('730','320','350','379','812','374')", 8: " ('113','174','131','115')", 9: " ('423','114')"}, 'code4': {0: 'nan', 1: 'nan', 2: " 'computer science'", 3: "  'computer science'", 4: " 'biology'", 5: " 'biology'", 6: "biology'", 7: "biology'", 8: 'nan', 9: 'nan'}, 'code5': {0: 'nan', 1: 'nan', 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: 'nan', 5: " ('12','18')", 6: " ('12','16','18','19')", 7: " ('12','18','19')", 8: " ('11','19','31')", 9: " '31'"}, 'code6': {0: 'nan', 1: " '594'", 2: 'nan', 3: 'nan', 4: " ('712','479','297','639','452','172')", 5: 'nan', 6: " ('285','295','236','239','269','284','237')", 7: 'nan', 8: " ('164','157','388','158')", 9: " ('372','238')"}, 'rules_desc': {0: 'rules1', 1: 'rules2', 2: 'rules2', 3: 'rules2', 4: 'rules2', 5: 'rules2', 6: 'rules2', 7: 'rules2', 8: 'rules2', 9: 'rules2'}}

mydf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
cols = mydf.columns.values
res=[",".join("{}:{}".format(*t) for t in zip(cols, row)) for _, row in mydf[cols].iterrows()]
res=[list(s.split('""')) for s in res]

intconv = lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1]))
for s in res:
    b = dict([i.split(':') for i in s])
    final = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in b.items())
    print(final)
```

but I have value error as follow:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [60], in <cell line: 9>()
> 8 intconv = lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1]))
> 9 for s in res:
> ---> 10     b = dict([i.split(':') for i in s])
> 11     final = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in b.items())
> 12     print(final)
>
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 9; 2 is
> required

not sure how to debug this, seems value can't accept list of string. the reason why I am doing this because I want to do key-value comparison. Does anyone know any workaround on this?

**desired output**

I don't want to try hard here. basically I want to create list of dictionary for each row of dataframe, where column_name is key and column value is value. I know in some column, its value is list of string, that's why I don't know how to create dictionary from it. here is the sample dictionary that I want:

```
output_dict={{'code0':'nan', 'code1': ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL'), 'code2':'nan', 'code3':'nan', 'code4':'nan', 'code5':'nan', 'code6':'nan','rules_desc': rules1},
{'code0': 40, 'code1':'nan','code2':'nan','code3':518, 'code4':'nan', 'code5':'nan','code6':594, 'rules_desc': rules2},
...
}
```

can we get dictionary something like this? because I want to create such list or dictionary to filter out another big dataframe. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question and put there expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks for heads up, yes, let me update in few sec.

Comment: Note that you receive this error because [i.split(':') for i in s] is a list (it's within brackets), that has one item - a list, that in turn has 9 items, which is why you are getting the error.
To insert to a dictionary your list must be of length 2 (key and value), and cannot be of length 9

Comment: @AndrejKesely do you mind if I ask one follow up question offline or separate discussion channel? don't know about ast library so I want to clarify one things if that's okay. thank you

Comment: @AndrejKesely we can still revert back `out` which is list of dictionary to dataframe, correct? Do you mind to show `pandas` approach instead of using `ast`? thanks

Comment: @AndrejKesely how can we drop element which has nan value in this list of dictionary? sorry for extra question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you have in `mydf` need *cleaning*. I'm using `ast.literal_eval` to try to convert the strings to tuples, and then `int()` the strings to integers:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

out = []
for _, row in mydf.iterrows():
    tmp = {}
    for k, v in zip(row.index, row):
        try:
            tmp[k] = literal_eval(v)

            if isinstance(tmp[k], str) and tmp[k].isnumeric():
                tmp[k] = int(tmp[k])
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            tmp[k] = v

    out.append(tmp)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "code0": "nan",
        "code1": ("VA", "HC", "NIH", "SAP", "AUS", "HOL", "ATT", "COL", "UCL"),
        "code2": "nan",
        "code3": "nan",
        "code4": "nan",
        "code5": "nan",
        "code6": "nan",
        "rules_desc": "rules1",
    },
    {
        "code0": 40,
        "code1": "nan",
        "code2": "nan",
        "code3": 518,
        "code4": "nan",
        "code5": "nan",
        "code6": 594,
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 98,
        "code1": ("ATT", "NC"),
        "code2": ("103", "104", "105", "106", "31"),
        "code3": 810,
        "code4": "computer science",
        "code5": "nan",
        "code6": "nan",
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 98,
        "code1": ("ATT", "VA", "NC"),
        "code2": ("104", "105", "106", "31"),
        "code3": "nan",
        "code4": "computer science",
        "code5": "nan",
        "code6": "nan",
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 52,
        "code1": "NC",
        "code2": 109,
        "code3": ("610", "620", "682", "642", "621", "611"),
        "code4": "biology",
        "code5": "nan",
        "code6": ("712", "479", "297", "639", "452", "172"),
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 52,
        "code1": "NC",
        "code2": 109,
        "code3": ("396", "340", "394", "393", "240"),
        "code4": "biology",
        "code5": ("12", "18"),
        "code6": "nan",
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 52,
        "code1": "NC",
        "code2": 109,
        "code3": ("612", "790", "110"),
        "code4": "biology'",
        "code5": ("12", "16", "18", "19"),
        "code6": ("285", "295", "236", "239", "269", "284", "237"),
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 52,
        "code1": "NC",
        "code2": 109,
        "code3": ("730", "320", "350", "379", "812", "374"),
        "code4": "biology'",
        "code5": ("12", "18", "19"),
        "code6": "nan",
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 40,
        "code1": "VA",
        "code2": 11,
        "code3": ("113", "174", "131", "115"),
        "code4": "nan",
        "code5": ("11", "19", "31"),
        "code6": ("164", "157", "388", "158"),
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
    {
        "code0": 58,
        "code1": "CE",
        "code2": 109,
        "code3": ("423", "114"),
        "code4": "nan",
        "code5": 31,
        "code6": ("372", "238"),
        "rules_desc": "rules2",
    },
]
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is great. Can I ask one question offline regarding this?

Comment: @Hamilton If you have question, it's better to post here. If I can I'll try to answer.

Comment: how can we drop element which has `nan` value in this list of dictionary?

Comment: @Hamilton You can do filtering afterwards: `out = [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != "nan"} for d in out]`

Comment: @Hamilton I'd recommend to open a new question here on stack overflow, where you describe the problem and what have you tried so far + expected output.

Comment: can we do above attempt in pandas instead of using `ast`? is that doable? if so, how? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question, but I think this will give you what you want - a list of dictionaries with key-value based on cols.

```
mydf.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Let me know if I missed something